# How can I merge several XML-documents into one without namespace accumulation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I have several SVG-segments in a table stored as xml-document. 
Now I need to select all elements from that table, and merge them into one XML-document.

This is the T-SQL code I have:

```
declare @xml table (xmldocument xml)
insert @xml select '
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" otherattrib="x">
  <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2"></path>
</svg>'

insert @xml select '
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" otherattrib="x">
  <admin>
  <g>
  <path></path>
  <path data-objid="0000X1"></path>
  <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2"></path>
  <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3"></path>
  </g>
  </admin>

    <g>
    <path></path>
    <path data-objid="0000X1"></path>
  <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2"></path>
  <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3"></path>
  </g>
</svg>'


insert @xml select '
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" otherattrib="x">
    <path></path>
</svg>'


insert @xml select '
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" otherattrib="x">
  <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3"></path>
</svg>'




--;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' AS svg)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
--SELECT 
    --(
        SELECT 
             --xmldocument 

            --,c.p.value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)')
            c.p.query('declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";.') 
        FROM @xml AS t

        OUTER APPLY t.xmldocument.nodes('/svg//*') AS c(p)

        FOR XML PATH(''), root('svg')
--  ) AS merged
```

But this produces

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <admin xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
      <path />
      <path data-objid="0000X1" />
      <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
      <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
    </g>
  </admin>
  <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path />
    <path data-objid="0000X1" />
    <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
    <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
  </g>
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-objid="0000X1" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
  <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path />
    <path data-objid="0000X1" />
    <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
    <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
  </g>
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-objid="0000X1" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
</svg>
```

instead of

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <admin>
    <g>
      <path />
      <path data-objid="0000X1" />
      <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
      <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
    </g>
  </admin>
  <g>
    <path />
    <path data-objid="0000X1" />
    <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
    <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
  </g>
  <path />
  <path data-objid="0000X1" />
  <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
  <g>
    <path />
    <path data-objid="0000X1" />
    <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
    <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
  </g>
  <path />
  <path data-objid="0000X1" />
  <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
  <path />
  <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
</svg>
```

What am I missing ? What do I do wrong ? 
How to correct this without having to cast to varchar and then do a search-and-replace on "xmlns=..." ?

Comment: [suppress namespace attributes in nested SELECT FOR XML statements](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements)

Comment: here is a work around but not sure if its as elegant as you want: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/08/28/suppressing-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-statements-when-using-for-xml-workaround/

Comment: I tested the method in Kamran's link against the varchar replace and stuff method and sadly the varchar method was not only faster but kept the query cleaner and easier to maintain.  Meanwhile, given it's been over 10 years since the problem was reported, a better solution doesn't seem likely anytime soon.

vote: 

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements

Comment: Btw: *copy'n'pasteable* test code, clear description, expected output, wrong output... Everything there which makes up a good question! +1

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The repeated namespaces are not wrong in any way, just annoying and bloating the size of your result...

Unfortunately there is no way to get rid of them in a clean way. Your idea of casting to text and do this on string level is not that bad, if you really need this (but be aware, that casting must go to **N**VARCHAR and the re-cast to XML can change your XML stucturally (attribute order, `CDATA`-sections...). Try this:

### Short approach

...if you really do not need anything else, than the namespace in the first root `<svg>`...

```
DECLARE @NewXML NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT t.xmldocument.query('declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";svg/*')
    FROM @xml AS t
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
SELECT CAST(N'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' 
          + REPLACE(@NewXML,' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"','') 
          + N'</svg>' AS XML);
```

### More flexible approach

You might try this:

```
DECLARE @NewXML XML=
(
    SELECT t.xmldocument.query('declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";svg/*')
    FROM @xml AS t
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
);
SET @NewXML =CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@NewXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"','') AS XML);
```

--You need to repeat the `CAST` and `REPLACE`, otherwise you'd get a lot of `xmlns=""` defining an empty default namespace for the inner nodes, which was wrong...

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
SELECT @NewXML=CAST(REPLACE(CAST((SELECT @NewXML FOR XML PATH('svg'),TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),' xmlns=""','') AS XML);
SELECT @NewXML;
```

### You might use `STUFF()` to introduce the namespace on string level:

(Don't use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` here...

```
SELECT @NewXML=CAST(STUFF(CAST((SELECT @NewXML FOR XML PATH('svg'),TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),5,0,' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ') AS XML);
SELECT @NewXML;
```

The result in all cases

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
  <admin>
    <g>
      <path />
      <path data-objid="0000X1" />
      <path id="123" data-objid="0000X2" />
      <path id="456" data-objid="0000X3" />
    </g>
  </admin>
  <g>
    <path />
    <path data-objid="0000X1" />
    <path id="789" data-objid="0000X2" />
    <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
  </g>
  <path />
  <path id="abc" data-objid="0000X3" />
</svg>
```